# Find the probability

Tags: probability, statistics

Three random steps in series are needed to complete a certain procedure.

Letting $\mu$ stand for the mean and $\sigma$ stand for the standard deviation, we have:

$$\mu_1 = 6,\quad \mu_2 = 4,\quad \mu_3 = 5$$

$$\sigma_1 = 2,\quad \sigma_2 = 2,\quad \sigma_3 = 3$$

everything in units of hours. Assuming independence and normal distributions, compute the probability that the procedure will be completed in less than 20 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $X_1+X_2+X_3$ has a normal distribution, also.  Figure out the mean and variance of the sum and then you're back in the familiar situation of checking whether a single normal random variable exceeds 20.  Interesting that time can be negative here.